# How to add more XAML pages or more XAML.cs pages to one XAML or one XAML.cs File In windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am an android Developer I am new to windows Phone 8

Recently i done an android application.. So i want to develop that application with same view and same functionality in windows Phone 8

In that part of developing, an android or iPhone application we can use one Design page with Different Coding pages.. or one coding page with different design

> I mean when i am developing my android  i used many XML files with one
>   java file,. and may Java files with one xml file..
>
> But where as in windows We have One XAML page to that we can add
>   one page XAML.cs It not possible To give same like android and iPhone.

If its there Please let me know..
*In my application i am Parsing the JSON data form a URL ,.. for that i have added a search engine so that user can search and that activity,and it will be parsed and displayed in another Page.*

In android I done this with one Two xaml files and one class file here its not possible,,

Is there any way to Do so.. in Windows Phone 8, If there Please Suggest.

Comment: Hey Madhu I think thats only Defect with Developers Phase So we don't have more Apps in windows phone.. But There should be another way to represent those files.

Comment: I know But Microsoft will have another way to represent they not leave it like this They almost copied ios and android But for this there should any kind i tried But No solution..

Comment: The Microsoft development stack follows a different methodology than Android development. Both platforms are capable of solving your problem, they just go about it in different ways. If I am understanding your problem correctly, you have two concerns: a page to search something, and a page to display the results. You want a single code-behind to handle both, correct? You can do this by creating a "ViewModel" class and sharing the ViewModel between both "Views". Read up on the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Its K avanek.. you Got my Question.. as a developer.. i am here to satisfy client..  But here I am parsing a JSON data From URL.. in any technology.. For parsing JSon froma a url. there is a search,filter and parsing json.. But i want For search One UI page and for parsing/displaying another UI page.. But its not possible .. Fist understand JSON from URL.. I am on that process.. If any suggestion please help me..

Answer (score 1):

In short NO.

Why you ask : In Visual Studio, there will be only one XAML.cs for every XAML file.  By that way your code will be more structured and will be tightly coupled with your design view. But you can create other classes and you can refer it in your XAML.cs class.

Comment: hi ajay GU.. i know how to design But at here I am parsing a data from  a URL In that If Url ex:Google.com/one/two If user user search one and two the data of that page should display.. but i need to create a Search page and display page separately.. so at here display page is main But how to Give code to search pages and how it is possible i am asking.. if is there any solution mention me.. That's all How can i create XAML.cs class by using this..